# Postfix "delivery temporarily suspended" sending to google apps

Tags: postfix, email, g-suite

I am getting the following errors when postfix is trying to send mail to my email address which is hosted using google apps:

```
Sep 15 10:24:53 zedsaid postfix/error[17246]: 07F246D1BCA: to=<www-data@zedsaid.com>, relay=none, delay=356386, delays=356313/73/0/0.02, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.com[74.125.157.27]:25: No route to host)
Sep 15 10:24:53 zedsaid postfix/error[17249]: 0D6F46D1B30: to=<www-data@zedsaid.com>, relay=none, delay=370784, delays=370710/73/0/0.02, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.com[74.125.157.27]:25: No route to host)
Sep 15 10:24:53 zedsaid postfix/error[17255]: 0648696A004: to=<www-data@zedsaid.com>, relay=none, delay=140987, delays=140914/73/0/0.02, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.com[74.125.157.27]:25: No route to host)
Sep 15 10:24:53 zedsaid postfix/error[17259]: 0F68C6D1F5F: to=<www-data@zedsaid.com>, relay=none, delay=264586, delays=264512/73/0/0.02, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.com[74.125.157.27]:25: No route to host)
Sep 15 10:24:53 zedsaid postfix/error[17247]: 06D3796A0EB: to=<www-data@zedsaid.com>, relay=none, delay=167, delays=94/73/0/0.02, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to ASPMX5.G:
```

The DNS for my mail is correctly setup to point to google's mail servers, so why would I be getting these errors?

Answer (score 6):

Can you telnet to `ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.com` on port 25?

- `telnet ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.com 25`

If you get no route to host, you should try the IP address directly:

- `telnet 74.125.157.27 25`

If this doesn't work, then you probably have an ISP that is blocking outbound connections to port 25. This is rather common these days to combat spam.

If this is the case you'll have to setup postfix to relay mail through your ISP's SMTP server. See the [relayhost](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost) configuration parameter.

Comment: Nope, I cannot connect to either of those.  I did move, and got a new ISP, so this must be the issue, because I didn't change anything on my server.

Comment: I have to use my ISP's SMTP?  Or can I use Google Apps?

Comment: @Zed: You have to use your ISP's as a relay. They are restricting your ability to connect to any SMTP server but theirs.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when **ipv6** addresses weren't being resolved properly. I fixed it by forcing **Postfix** to use **ipv4**.

```
vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Amend, or add, this line

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Answer (score 0):

The text of your log files says "No route to host" -- this *could* be because your ISP is blocking outgoing smtp traffic, but is not the only reason. (For example, if your linux box has a static route that is no longer valid, you'd get something like the results you are seeing.)

Do you have lft installed on your linux box?  If so, with superuser privileges, issue this command: `lft aspmx5.googlemail.com:25`  -- this should tell you where you are being blocked.

(lft allows you to use tcp for traceroute)